# matplotlib add rectangle to Figure not to Axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to add a semi transparent skin over my matplotlib figure. I was thinking about adding a rectangle to the figure with alpha <1  and a zorder high enough so its drawn on top of everything.

I was thinking about something like that

```
figure.add_patch(Rectangle((0,0),1,1, alpha=0.5, zorder=1000))
```

But I guess rectangles are handled by Axes only. is there any turn around ?

Comment: _why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: @tacaswell to Show an encompassing Frame around multiple subplots.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a *phantom* axes on top of your figure and change the patch to look as you like, try this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.set_zorder(1000)
ax.patch.set_alpha(0.5)
ax.patch.set_color('r')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2.plot(range(10), range(10))

plt.show()
```

Comment: To make this work better with things like `tight_layout`, create the phantom axes by cloning an existing one with `ax.twinx()`.

Answer (score 38):

Late answer for others who google this.

There actually is a simple way, without phantom axes, close to your original wish. The `Figure` object has a `patches` attribute, to which you can add the rectangle:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
ax.plot(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(100)))
fig.patches.extend([plt.Rectangle((0.25,0.5),0.25,0.25,
                                  fill=True, color='g', alpha=0.5, zorder=1000,
                                  transform=fig.transFigure, figure=fig)])
```

Gives the following picture (I'm using a non-default theme):

[image: Plot with rectangle attached to figure]

The `transform` argument makes it use figure-level coordinates, which I think is what you want.

Comment: This works like a charm even with matplotlib 3.0.0 and Python 3.6!

Comment: Works great for me too, but if you're using ``figure(constrained_layout=True)`` make sure to call ``fig.execute_constrained_layout()`` after plotting the data and before creating the patch.

Comment: Good call. Or `fig.get_layout_engine().execute()` in newer matplotlib versions.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't using subplots, using `gca()` will work easily.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.plot([0,100],[0,100])
plt.gca().add_patch(Rectangle((25,50),15,15,fill=True, color='g', alpha=0.5, zorder=100, figure=fig))
```

[image]