# Disable matplotlib widget in PyQt

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas, pyqt, figure

I have a pyQt application with several embedded matplotlib widgets (https://github.com/chipmuenk/pyFDA).

The automatic updating of plots can be turned off for each plotting widget to speed up the application (especially 3D plots can take quite long).

Unfortunately, I haven't managed to disable (grey out) the canvas completely yet. What I'd like is to do something like

```
class MplWidget(QWidget):
    """
    Construct a subwidget with Matplotlib canvas and NavigationToolbar
    """

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MplWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        # Create the mpl figure and construct the canvas with the figure
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.pltCanv = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
#-------------------------------------------------

self.mplwidget = MplWidget(self)
self.mplwidget.pltCanv.setEnabled(False) # <- this doesn't work
```

to make it clear that there is nothing to interact with in this widget. Is there an easy workaround?

Comment: Is this about changing the color to grey or about preventing any user interaction?

Comment: Preventing any user interaction would be better but "greying out" would be sufficient. But I haven't even managed to do that ...

Comment: Greying: Use a patch as large as the figure, set its zorder very high, make it semitransparent. Preventing user interaction: disconnect all events from the canvas (this is a matplotlib operation, not one of PyQt). (I guess I could provide an answer, but in case of the second option it would be necessary to have a [mcve] available for testing.)

Comment: No thanks, using a patch is fine for me - the other option sounds too complicated for a small UI improvement. As a third alternative, I'm clearing the figure (`clf()`) - not too pretty, but it also does the job. If you repost the patch solution as an answer, I could give you a credit.

Comment: Although I'm aware this question has a different (visual) context - since it contains "Disable matplotlib widget": there is also a [`matplotlib.widgets.Widget.set_active(active)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Widget.set_active), which probably corresponds to disabling a widget. Note, though, that `set_active` for Radio and CheckButtons has different meaning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Grey out figure.

You may grey out the figure by placing a grey, semitransparent patch on top of it. To this end, you may create a Rectangle, set its zorder very high and give it the figure transform. To add it to a an axes, you may use `ax.add_patch`; however in order to add it to a figure with a 3D axes, this will not work and you would need to add it via `fig.patches.extend`. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41912643/4124317))

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot([1,3,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,2])

rect=plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1, transform=fig.transFigure, 
                   clip_on=False, zorder=100, alpha=0.5, color="grey")
fig.patches.extend([rect])

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Disconnecting all events

You may disconnect all events from the canvas. This will prevent any user interaction, but is also not reversible; so if you need those events back at a later stage the solution would be more complicated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot([1,3,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,2])

for evt, callback in fig.canvas.callbacks.callbacks.items():
    for cid, _ in callback.items():
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanx for extending your answer to 3D axes as well (which I do need)!